# poetry install --> not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, fastapi, python-poetry, uvicorn, pyproject.toml

I have my `pyproject.toml` file in the root of my project. It looks something like this (names changed for simplicity/discretion, but works the same):

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "controller_poc"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Controller (API) POC"
license = "MIT"
authors = ["Felipe Freitas"]
readme = "README.md"
repository = "https://github.com/felipefreitassilva/..."
keywords = ["Controller", "POC"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
fastapi = "0.103.1"
pylint = "2.17.6"
pydantic = "2.3.0"
uvicorn = "0.23.2"
python-multipart = "0.0.6"
httpx = "0.25.0"

sqlalchemy = {version = "2.0.20", extras = ["sqlite"]}
sqlalchemy_utils = "0.41.1"
pymysql = "1.0.2"

autopep8 = "2.0.4"
pytest = "7.4.2"
pytest-cov = "4.1.0"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "app.main:start"
test = "pytest"
lint = "autopep8 --in-place --recursive ."

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

If I run poetry install from the root, all goes correctly:

```
C:\Users\Felipe\Controller_POC> poetry install
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

However, if I attempt to run the start command, like so:

```
C:\Users\Felipe\Controller_POC> poetry run start
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.

No file/folder found for package controller-poc
```

It throws this error - which has nothing to do with the script itself, the script works normally (and looks like this) if it matters:

```py
def start():
    """
    Run the application with uvicorn
    """
    from uvicorn import run
    run('app.main:app',
        reload=True,
        workers=1,
        host=settings.API_HOST,
        port=settings.API_PORT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

However, and this is *where the problem occurs*:

If I add the package, using [pyproject's tool > packages option](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages), like so:

```
pyproject.toml

...
keywords = ["Controller", "POC"]
packages=[{ include="app" }]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
...
```

and attempt to run `poetry install` again, it throws a new error

```
C:\Users\Felipe\Controller_POC> poetry install
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update

Installing the current project: controller_poc (0.1.0)

not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

That being said, altough it "creates" this previously non existing error, it also fixes the `start` script:

```
C:\Users\Felipe\Controller_POC> poetry run start
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\Felipe\\Controller_POC']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [3336] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [7372]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

I have no idea why this "seesaw" effect happens, and I have tried and tried through many forums, documentations and other sources, but I can't seem to find what is happening

I'm somewhat new to python, perhaps it doesn't work as I expect and I should change completely to another tool. I read about [poethepoet](https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet), but don't know weather it is secure and if it would do what I intended.

If someone could give me any directions, I would deeply appreciate it

Comment: Re: "Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.", what interpreter have you configured poetry to use? Also, what version of poetry are your using, and what installation method did you use?

Comment: Side note: `test` probably isn't the best name for distribution script, since that will clash with Unix `test`

Comment: I ran these 2 commands to install poetry
`pip install poetry==1.4.1`
`poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`

Comment: Thank you for the `test` feedback, I had no idea

Comment: Installing poetry with pip is not recommended, since that will mix poetry's dependencies with whatever is in your current environment / whatever you install later. You can install poetry in its own isolated environment [with pipx](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-pipx) (`pip install pipx; pipx install poetry`) or using [poetry's own installer](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer). The current poetry release is 1.6.1, so you might also consider upgrading to rule out already patched bugs.

Comment: Assuming `app` is `app.py`, that is not your package. Follow the project structure shown in the [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#project-setup) and put your `.py` files into a folder _below_ where your `pyproject.toml` resides. _That folder_ is your package.